# Symfony controller with URL parameters and injected services

Tags: symfony, controller

In Symfony 3.4 I have a controller, which has some parameters filled from the URL and also I need a service to be injected. I get the following error message:

> Controller
>   "Acs\EventNodeBundle\Controller\MainController::calendarAction()"
>   requires that you provide a value for the "$router" argument. Either
>   the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no
>   default value has been provided or because there is a non optional
>   argument after this one.

Why don't Symfony injects the Router? This is my code:

The controller:

```
...

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Routing\Router;

/**
 * Class MainController
 */
class MainController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @param Router   $router
     * @param null|int $year
     * @param null|int $month
     * @return RedirectResponse|Response
     */
    public function calendarAction(Router $router, $year = null, $month = null)
    {
...
```

The services.yml:

```
...
services:
    # default configuration for services in *this* file
    _defaults:
        # automatically injects dependencies in services
        autowire: true
        # automatically registers services as commands, event subscribers, etc.
        autoconfigure: true
        # services cannot be fetched directly from the container via $container->get()
        # need to override this setting individually
        public: false

        bind:
            $entityManager: '@Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface'

   # enable autowiring for controllers
   Acs\EventNodeBundle\Controller\:
       resource: '../../Controller'
       public: true
       tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
...
```

And the routing:

```
...
    eventnode_main:
        path: /{year}/{month}
        methods: [GET]
        defaults: { _controller: AcsEventNodeBundle:Main:calendar, year: null, month: null}
        requirements:
            year: '\d+'
            month: '\d+'
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A constructor in your Controller should do the job:

```
/**
 * MainController constructor.
 *
 * @param Router $router
 */
public function __construct(
    Router $router
) {
    $this->router = $router;
}
```

Comment: This solved the problem, thank you. Just for the record is this caused by the fact I try to inject a service and URL params into the controller method at the same time? Because in another controller which does not use params from the URL I could simply inject services into the controller method itself and not the controller constructor.

Comment: I think you could also add the Services after the route parameters, as described here: https://symfony.com/doc/current/controller.html#fetching-services.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this in your services.yml :

```
Acs\EventNodeBundle\:
    resource: '../../src/EventNodeBundle/*'
```

This will make classes in src/EventNodeBundle available to be used as services.

See this documentation :
https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/service_container/3.3-di-changes.html